# How to set user classpath precedence when not a mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop

My class looks like this

```
public class generateAll extends Configured implements Tool
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    ToolRunner.run(new generateAll(), args);
}
.
.
.
```

What i want is, to execute the program using hadoop jar command, because i am using getConf() statement inside program.

There is no mapper reducer involved.

There is already a hsqldb 1.8 in hadoop libs
My program is using hsqlsb 2.2.9 ( as a maven dependency)

There is a method in jobConf to override hadoop classpath with user classpath, But since my program doesnt involve map/reduce , How to override hadoop classpath ?

The program is running fine when run as a test file. 
hadoop version  - cdh3u3

The error thrown while using hadoop jar command is:

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token AS, requires ( in statement [create table click as]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.inmobi.qa.SQLUtil.SQLScriptExecuter.executeScript(SQLScriptExecuter.java:62)
    at com.inmobi.qa.logboxtools.generateAll.test_table_creation(generateAll.java:186)
    at com.inmobi.qa.logboxtools.generateAll.run(generateAll.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.inmobi.qa.logboxtools.generateAll.main(generateAll.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)

Comment: if hsqldb 2.2.9 had been loaded(which i provided as maven dependency),it would have worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following commands before you run `hadoop jar`.

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=your_classpath:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

your_classpath should contain hsqlsb 2.2.9.

Comment: but that will change classpath for all the jobs i am gonna run after. How can i prevent that?

Comment: It's hard to do it as the Java ClassLoader delegation model: `When requested to find a class or resource, a ClassLoader instance will delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself.` So if hsqldb 1.8 is loaded, you can not replace it to hsqlsb 2.2.9 in most cases.